# "doing something on command" or doing something after one's command"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please which is the correct and natural way to say that someone wants someone to do things only after the person tells that person to do the things. Here is the context:

> Do not do anything with the bar until I tell you to do something. Every move must be performed **after my command**/**on command**.

I am in doubt that my options are natural, but I cannot come up with something that is sounds native, so tell me please natural phrases to convey the meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to "on my command" you could say

> Every move must be done *on command*.

Compare

> The dog rolls over on command.
>
> This device will stream music on command.

There is also the related phrase **on my mark**, which is used in situations where a single action must be initiated rather than a series of actions:

> On my mark ... ready, set, go!

Those are the words of someone who is the starter for a race.

Comment: Are the phrase "on command" are ok in terms of weightlifting?

Comment: Yes. If you said to me: "Don't do anything until I tell you to do it, and when I tell you to do it, you must do it *on command*."   I would understand you to mean "Wait for my command before you do anything, and when you hear my command, don't delay but immediately do what you are told."

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with "on my command".

It's a more natural way of saying that.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.